# Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node-modules

I am trying to setup existing nodejs project on my window

```
Npm -v :- 6.0.1
node -v :- v8.11.1
```

When i run node app.js i am getting following error

> include-all attempted to
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\sails\backend\api\services\FileUploadService.js)`,
>   but an error occurred::
>       Details:Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
>           at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>           at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>           at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>           at evalmachine.:31:26
>           at Object. (C:\xampp\htdocs\sails\backend\node_modules\s3\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>           at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>           at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>           at Object. (C:\xampp\htdocs\sails\backend\node_modules\s3\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>           at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>           at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>           at Object. (C:\xampp\htdocs\sails\backend\node_modules\s3\lib\index.js:3:10)

Any idea? what i am missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same issue.  After researching it, it looks like there are many ways that people have fix this problem.

What caused the problem for me was that I upgraded node and needed to rebuild my project.

> npm rebuild

Fixed it for me.

There is a lengthy discussion here:
[nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1124)

Comment: `npm rebuild` didn't help me.

Comment: this works for me, sudo n 6.12.0, it s the answer below

Comment: `npm rebuild` threw errors and didn't help. Instead, I followed the error stack of the command line and re-install every module it mentioned. And it worked.

Comment: you can use nvm and usually moving back and forth between npm versions should help

Answer (score 2):

Reverting to an earlier version, resolved the crash I was getting each time I run `npm` :

```
sudo n 6.12.0
```

Thanks to: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1124#issuecomment-345181229

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 I recently had error message also, running `nodejs`. This error would occur even if I simply ran something simple like `npm --version`.

I then noticed the error stack trace showed the following script in the call stack:

> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)

It turns out that an earlier version of `npm` had installed scripts in the user's profile folder and, for some reason, that never got removed - even though I had performed many uninstalls and reinstalls of the latest `nodejs` version.

Simply removing the entire `npm` folder under `C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Roaming\npm` solved the issue.

The latest `npm` installs these scripts in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm`, which is where these should be picked up.